# what does returns row_array() in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

in my modal
I want to get a list of email addresses from the database, what I have tried are here:

In my model:

```
function get_email_address_by_sector($search_by, $search_field) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->like($search_by, $search_field);
        $query = $this->db->get('tb_company');

        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row['email'];
    }
```

I want to see the data in the array with this controller:

```
function get_email_address($search_by, $search_field) {
        $recipients = $this->company_model->get_email_address_by_sector($search_by, $search_field);

        print_r($recipients);
    }
```

what does returns  row_array() in  codeigniter.

Comment: check the doc https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `row_array()` and `row()` will return only one row. Use `result_array()` or `result()` if you want to fetch multiple rows. See [result_array()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays)

Change `$row = $query->row_array();` to `$row = $query->result_array();`